# MYSQL INNER JOINS

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my database. One is used for booking from a selection of dates and times available and the other is used for returning from a selection of dates and times available. I need to link these two together on one page. [image]

```
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["User_id"]);
    $query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.return_time, t2.return_date FROM Returnout AS t1 INNER JOIN Return AS t2 ON t1.book_time=t2.book_time";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

    //this selects the results as rows
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    

    $dates_and_times = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dates_and_times[] = $row['book_date'].' '.$row['book_time'];
        $dates_and_times[] = $row['return_date'].' '.$row['retun_time'];
    }
}
?>      
        <form method="post" action="booked.php">
    <strong>Dates available</strong>            
    <select id="Date" name="Date">                      
    <option value="0">--Select date--</option>
    <?php  foreach ($dates_and_times as $app_date) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $app_date; ?>"><?php echo $app_date; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

So I need to have 2 forms, 1 displaying the dates and times for booking and the other for returning. I have gone wrong somewhere with the INNER JOINS. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: gone wrong how? wrong results? joins the wrong tables? returns bad data? Perhaps the typo in at `$row['retun_time']`?

Comment: Before moving forward with your project, switch to [MySQLi (MySQL Improved)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). However to answer your question, what is your expected output, and what is the provided output?

Comment: doesn't display the selection of dates and times which are stored in the database. I think its my INNER JOIN statement

Comment: Data is stored in the database like the dates and times. The outcome is for these to display to the user

Comment: are you sure you have matching records in both table with exact time? try LEFT!!

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: @zod, both tables have different data as one is for booking and other is for returning so times and dates in both tables are different

Comment: Some data may be different , but there should be a  matching key in both tables , then only you will get result on joining . is it? If you post sample data too, that will be great

Comment: I have not used any primary keys. Would this be the reason?